# How do you find what process is holding a file open in Windows?

Tags: windows, file-sharing

One thing that annoys me no end about Windows is the old **sharing violation** error. Often you can't identify what's holding it open. Usually it's just an editor or explorer just pointing to a relevant directory but sometimes I've had to resort to rebooting my machine.

Any suggestions on how to find the culprit?

Comment: You would think that after all this time, the Windows guys would give us a way to do this easily from within Explorer. I wonder why this hasn't happened?

Comment: I find that Explorer is very often the problem process that is holding onto a file for no obvious reason.

Comment: I know this doesn't help you much, but I think I remembered that this was a planned feature of the next Windows release after vista and 2008 server.  or maybe it's a WinFS thing.  not sure where i read that...

Comment: see my answer on [superuser here](https://superuser.com/a/1485069/16847), in summary [OpenedFilesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) still works in 2019

Comment: 2021... Issue still exists in Windows 10. Randomly got to this question on unrelated search. When I stumble upon this problem with something holding the file, it's often `explorer.exe` as Eddie suggested, I kill `explorer.exe` from Task Manager, this fixes the issue and disables almost all UI. Now you need to restart your `explorer.exe`, I just press Win+R and type `explorer.exe` there and press enter, it starts `explorer.exe` and life is good again :).

Comment: Hard Mode: Without installing anything (no Sysinternals) and without admin access (no resmon)

I don't think it's possible - for the average cubicle jockey that doesn't have admin rights and isn't allowed to install utilities, you're probably going to have to cough up the 5 minutes of your work day and reboot.

Comment: Besides explorer.exe another common reason of unnecessary file locking is "Application Experience" service (AeLookupSvc). Its description clearly says that it processes app compatibility cache requests for apps "*as they are launched*".
I had sporadic file access problem during parallel builds when my makefile ran numerous "CorFlags.exe" to modify an .exe immediately after it has been built. With "Process Monitor" tool I figured out that it is locked by svchost.exe of a certain PID. Experimental way I found that that PID was AeLookupSvc. Since I disabled this service my builds run stable.

Answer (score 519):

I've had success with [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  With this, you can search to find what process(es) have a file open, and you can use it to close the handle(s) if you want. Of course, it is safer to close the whole process.  Exercise caution and judgement.

To find a specific file, use the menu option `Find->Find Handle or DLL...`  Type in part of the path to the file.  The list of processes will appear below.

If you prefer command line, Sysinternals suite includes command line tool [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx), that lists open handles.

**Examples**

- `c:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite>handle.exe |findstr /i "e:\"` (finds all files opened from drive `e:\`"
- `c:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite>handle.exe |findstr /i "file-or-path-in-question"`

Comment: You can close the handle, but keep in mind, you're pulling the rug out from under an application, results will be unpredictable at best.

Comment: @Walden: Absolutely.  YMMV.  With WinXP, I've many times had Explorer open a handle for no obvious reason and refuse to close it.  When this happens on a file you need to delete, you have the choice of forcing the handle closed, or rebooting.  So far, having done this dozens of times, I have suffered no ill effect.  As with any advanced tool, use with caution and judgment.

Comment: Closing the handles can cause the app to re-use the handle on another file, causing corruption - see Jeff's answer below: http://serverfault.com/a/15695/79266 ... much safer to kill the application holding the file open, if you don't want to reboot.

Comment: For explorer, btw, hold ctrl-shift and right-click a blank area of the start menu, and you'll get "Exit Explorer" - ps, not quite Jeff's answer..

Comment: I have on more than one occasion had this cause a blue screen for me. Closing random handle to a file.

Comment: processexplorer (and most of the Sysinternals tools) is great. Use it to find the process which have the handle open, but then close the process (not the handle!) (see below for Raymond's Chen nice explanation about the danger of closing the handle! in a nutshell, that handle once closed could be reused by another app, and therefore point to another file. The original app could then maybe write/close/change that other file, thinking it's still pointing to the original file! Possibly causing corruption in the new file pointed at.)

Comment: It doesn't help for non executive file i.g. a text file. I need to know who is writing to a log file. Any idea?

Comment: sure this works for a text file.  It doesn't care what kind of file is open.

Comment: Process Explorer solved the problem for me. The weird thing is that it was the flash player plugin, a sub-process of the browser. I don't understand why that was, but it's a mystery for another time.

Comment: It should be noted that ProcessExplorer must be run _as Administrator_ or it may not able to see files open by system processes.

Comment: @MarkSowul I don't see that menu in Win10. To restart explorer I normally run `taskkill /f /im:explorer.exe` then open task manager and run `explorer`

Comment: It's not longer there in Windows 10.  But now you'll see "Restart" (instead of "End Task") if you select Windows Explorer in Task Manager (in "processes" after selecting "more details", if you have only the simple task list currently shown).

Comment: @Xaqron I'm having the same problem.  My log file isn't on my C:\ drive, it's on my D:\ drive.  I'm wondering if that's the reason why when I search for the file name, it doesn't show in the results.  I've also tried putting in the path and file name into the search box, still doesn't find it.

Comment: 0 results, file is still locked...

Comment: While useful, Process Explorer really didn't tell me what the problem was - having the drive shared.  Once I turned off sharing for the drive, the open handles went away.

Comment: Make sure Process Explorer is in "Handle Mode". View > Lower Pane Mode, or press `Ctrl + H`.

Comment: you don't need to use `findstr`. v4.22 and perhaps earlier ` handle` will search by name: e.g. `handle name-fragament-i-cant-delete`. This method also shows more info than the findstr method does: https://i.imgur.com/JYtVLvM.png

Comment: Using handle, I found I had to escape the backslash, ie "E:\\"

Answer (score 314):

You can use the **Resource Monitor** for this which comes **built-in** with Windows 7, 8, and 10.

1. Open **Resource Monitor**, which can be found

   - By searching for **Resource Monitor** or  **resmon.exe** in the start menu, or
   - As a button on the **Performance** tab in your *Task Manager*
2. Go to the **CPU** tab
3. Use the **search field** in the **Associated Handles** section

   - See blue arrow in screen shot below

When you've found the handle, you can identify the process by looking at the Image and/or PID column.

You can then try to close the application as you normally would, or, if that's not possible, just right-click the handle and kill the process directly from there. Easy peasy!

[image: Resource Monitor screenshot]

*Copied from my original answer: https://superuser.com/a/643312/62*

Comment: It's worth noting that it can be hard to find this program on Windows 8 - a search for 'resmon.exe' should locate it.

Comment: @Kylotan, Stop wasting time searching. Just run `resmon`  directly from cmd

Comment: @Pacerier: Nice. I'm not used to things being in the Windows path.

Comment: This suits me better than 'Handle | FindStr' and 'Unlocker' alternatives, although they are also effective

Comment: This also helps find what's locking a folder the same way. Great solution!

Comment: Also in Windows 2012

Comment: I know it's old, but did the trick for me!

Comment: @Kylotan A lot of builtins are in the path, actually! (`control`, `iexplore`, etc) Super+R is faster than searching, and convenient when you don't have a command window open already.

Comment: Still valid in Windows 10 and can be found by using the "Open Resource Monitor" button inside Task Manager -> Performance tab.

Comment: Best solution IMHO - works in Win10 without having to install any third-party software.

Comment: @rainabba How does it works with folders?

Comment: Once you find the PID you can use the details window in Task Manager to identify _who_ has it open and you can go tip a bucket of slime on them

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Or, you can just look under Processes, just above the block with Associated Handles you're already looking at...

Comment: @cletus This should be the accepted answer as it doesn't require third-party software

Answer (score 106):

Just be very careful with closing handles; it's even more dangerous than you'd think, because of handle recycling - if you close the file handle, and the program opens something else, that original file handle you closed may be reused for that "something else."  And now guess what happens if the program continues, thinking it is working on the file (whose handle you closed), when in fact that file handle is now pointing to something else.

see [Raymond Chen's post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx) on this topic

> Suppose a search index service has a file open for indexing but has
> gotten stuck temporarily and you want to delete the file, so you
> (unwisely) force the handle closed. The search index service opens its
> log file in order to record some information, and the handle to the
> deleted file is recycled as the handle to the log file. The stuck
> operation finally completes, and the search index service finally gets
> around to closing that handle it had open, but it ends up unwittingly
> closing the log file handle.
>
> The search index service opens another
> file, say a configuration file for writing so it can update some
> persistent state. The handle for the log file gets recycled as the
> handle for the configuration file. The search index service wants to
> log some information, so it writes to its log file. Unfortunately, the
> log file handle was closed and the handle reused for its configuration
> file. The logged information goes into the configuration file,
> corrupting it.
>
> Meanwhile, another handle you forced closed was reused
> as a mutex handle, which is used to help prevent data from being
> corrupted. When the original file handle is closed, the mutex handle
> is closed and the protections against data corruption are lost. The
> longer the service runs, the more corrupted its indexes become.
> Eventually, somebody notices the index is returning incorrect results.
> And when you try to restart the service, it fails because its
> configuration files have been corrupted.
>
> You report the problem to the
> company that makes the search index service and they determine that
> the index has been corrupted, the log file has mysteriously stopped
> logging, and the configuration file was overwritten with garbage. Some
> poor technician is assigned the hopeless task of figuring out why the
> service corrupts its indexes and configuration files, unaware that the
> source of the corruption is that you forced a handle closed.

Comment: important warning, this should go nearer the top - a reboot is probably better than a silently corrupted file.

Comment: +1 This will certainly make me think twice about forcing handles closed!

It seems strange to me that Windows would immediately re-use the number of a closed handle, rather than continuing to increment the number and only wrapping around when necessary. That would at least greatly reduce the chances of this problem happening.

Comment: @RichVel Terminating the culprit process is probably better than a complete reboot.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - good point, and in fact I already mentioned that [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows#comment383110_1980)

Comment: Wow.  Raymond Chen blows me away every time I read something he writes.

Comment: This is a very important warning, but doesn't answer the question *How do you find what process is holding a file open in Windows?*

Comment: This is probably a "legacy" characteristic of Windows which they never changed, but still very much need to change because it is a security vulnerability.  Since "handles" are simply integers, they should never be re-issued.  (Even if the underlying resource, the open-files table entries, are of course reused.)

Comment: I don't think it is a security vulnerability.  The process already has access to whatever it had access to.  Raymond describes this situation as "It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway" -- a recent example:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200203-00/?p=103391

Comment: This probably isn't likely to change -- it's probably not a deliberate reuse; handles can just be "the memory address of this thing", and as memory is freed and reused, so too do the "handle values" get reused.

Comment: @EM0 that's an entirely sensible improvement which a majority of ordinary people support. It's a shame none of the general computing population has the legal right to just, you know, fix the operating system's flaw ourselves to improve everyone's lives.

Answer (score 99):

If you are having enough privileges, try the [openfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/openfiles) command.

You might have to enable listing of localy opened files by running `openfiles /local on` and rebooting.

Comment: +1 for a builtin command, although I personally use ProcessExplorer for this most of the time.

Comment: Really helpful.

Comment: ERROR: The target system must be running a 32 bit OS.

Comment: doesn't work for 64 OS!

Comment: This looks to be working for Windows 2012R2 64bit, but you need to enable the "open local tracking" service by running `openfiles /local on` and restarting. This makes this feature not very useful.

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>openfiles /local on`

`SUCCESS: The system global flag 'maintain objects list' is enabled.
         This will take effect after the system is restarted.`

Oh great, that was helpful thanks.

Comment: John all contributions are appreciated, I was not aware of this command, thank you.  What do you think of editing the answer to clarify it requires a 32-bit system, or possibly turning on a service to work with 64-bit versions?   As @Guss and others have pointed out, sometimes alternates paths may be more optimal.  You might save people sum total lots of time (a bit of time x number of users reading the answer) .  Respectfully -

Answer (score 29):

I've used [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) with success to find such processes in the past.

Comment: I use this tool all the time.  If I can't eject a USB drive, I just type "handle H:" (or whatever the drive letter).  Best of all, you can use it to force close handles.

Comment: I've been told so many times at SO that link-only answers are discouraged. With this here now I'm one of those purists. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Lockhunter (http://lockhunter.com/) works on 32 and 64bit systems.

Comment: It's also available from that file's context menu in Windows Explorer.

Comment: In my case none of other answers worked, also Lockhunter when I typed in the file name did not find any process locking it, but the context menu option worked! Thanks!

Comment: I've been told so many times at SO that link-only answers are discouraged. With this here now I'm one of those purists; and even a double one. ;)

Comment: @GeroldBroser this was one of the best answers I've seen here and it's "link only". You might wanna rethink your last statement lol

Comment: @Gaspa79 My last statement is the "double one". And this is still true. See my comment to [the answer above(AToW)](https://serverfault.com/a/1970/249782). :)

Comment: @GeroldBroser Lol wtf. This link only answer is still one of the best I've seen in SO.

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify, this is more likely to be a result of misbehaving 3rd party apps not using the **CreateFile** API call correctly than it is to be anything in Windows itself.  Perhaps it's a consequence of the design of CreateFile, but done is done and we can't go back.

Basically when opening a file in a Windows program you have the option to specify a flag that allows shared access.  If you don't specify the flag, the program takes exclusive access of the file.

Now, if Explorer seems to be the culprit here, it may be the case that that's just on the surface, and that the true culprit is something that installs a shell extension that opens all files in a folder for it's own purposes but is either too gung-ho in doing so, or that doesn't clean up properly after itself.  Symantec AV is something I've seen doing this before, and I wouldn't be surprised if other AV programs were also to blame.  Source control plug-ins may also be at fault.

So not really an answer, but just some advice to not always blame Windows for what may be a badly written 3rd party program (something that can also happen on any other OS which has implicit file locking, but any unix based OS has shared access by default).

Comment: I won't blame a 3rd party app on the fact that my windows explorer always locks Thumbs.db files in its working directory, but does not always unlock it when I switch working directory. At least they are unlocked when I close the window, I don't have to kill ALL explorers...

Comment: @Darth, Are you a marketer from Microsoft?

Answer (score 6):

On a remote server, when you're checking on a network share, something as simple as the Computer Management console can display this information and close the file.

Comment: Exactly, why are there such complicated answers ?

Comment: The question is not in the context of a network share being held open by another remote user on the network, but of a file or folder being held open by a process on the local machine.

Answer (score 6):

[Who Lock Me](https://web.archive.org/web/20160102121459/http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) works well and keeps people amused with the name!

Comment: Doesn't work in 64-bit Windows 8 and 10.

Comment: I've been told so many times at SO that link-only answers are discouraged. With this here now I'm one of those purists; and even a triple one. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Apropos Explorer holding a file open: "When this happens on a file you need to delete, you have the choice of forcing the handle closed, or rebooting."

You can just end Explorer.

If this is a one-time thing (Explorer does not normally hold this file open) then I would guess logging off and logging back on will do the trick.

Otherwise, kill the desktop Explorer process and do what you want while it's gone. First start a copy of cmd.exe (you need a UI to do your intended cleanup). Make sure there are no non-desktop Explorers running. Then kill the last Explorer with, e.g., Task Manager. Do what you want in the command prompt. Finally, run Explorer from the command prompt, and it will become the desktop.

I'd guess there may be some residual unpleasantness if some systray programs can't deal with the shell restarting.

Comment: This is much safer than closing the handle, and less disruptive than rebooting.  Applies to other programs too - I often find a Microsoft Office program holds locks on files even after I've closed them.

Answer (score 5):

Files can be locked by local processes ([unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/) is the tool to use) and by file access that comes in through shares.

There is a built-in function in Windows that shows you what files on the local computer are open/locked by remote computer (which has the file open through a file share):

```
* Select "Manage Computer" (Open "Computer Management")
* click "Shared Folders"
* choose "Open Files"
```

There you can even close the file forcefully.

Answer (score 4):

With [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) you can identify what processes are holding your files easily:

[image: Find Handles or DLLs]

Answer (score 3):

There is NirSoft's [Opened Files View](http://nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) as well.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Personally I like this better than Process Explorer for this specific tasks.

Comment: I've been told so many times at SO that link-only answers are discouraged. With this here now I'm one of those purists; and even a quadruple one. ;)

Comment: @GeroldBroser: You seem to have a wrong impression of "link-only answer".  It does not mean that the answer contains a link which is relevant to the entire answer.  It means that if the link cannot be followed (e.g. you look at a screenshot of the answer) that all information is lost.  That isn't the case here, with no links this is still a valid answer (and already was in the version you commented on, as the text alone was meaningful, although the image definitely improved the answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it programmatically by leveraging on the NTDLL/KERNEL32 Windows API. E.g. have a look at the following code in Python:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

path = r"C:\temp\test.txt"

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# generic strings and constants
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ntdll = ctypes.WinDLL('ntdll')
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

NTSTATUS = wintypes.LONG

INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80
FILE_SHARE_READ = 1
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000

FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS = wintypes.ULONG
FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation = 47

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = wintypes.LPVOID
ULONG_PTR = wintypes.WPARAM


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# create handle on concerned file with dwDesiredAccess == FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

kernel32.CreateFileW.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.CreateFileW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,      # In     lpFileName
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwDesiredAccess
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwShareMode
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # In_opt lpSecurityAttributes
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwCreationDisposition
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwFlagsAndAttributes
    wintypes.HANDLE)       # In_opt hTemplateFile
hFile = kernel32.CreateFileW(
    path, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ, None, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, None)
if hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
    raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# prepare data types for system call
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class IO_STATUS_BLOCK(ctypes.Structure):
    class _STATUS(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (('Status', NTSTATUS),
                    ('Pointer', wintypes.LPVOID))
    _anonymous_ = '_Status',
    _fields_ = (('_Status', _STATUS),
                ('Information', ULONG_PTR))


iosb = IO_STATUS_BLOCK()


class FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('NumberOfProcessIdsInList', wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('ProcessIdList', wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER * 64))


info = FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION()

PIO_STATUS_BLOCK = ctypes.POINTER(IO_STATUS_BLOCK)
ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile.restype = NTSTATUS
ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # In  FileHandle
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,       # Out IoStatusBlock
    wintypes.LPVOID,        # Out FileInformation
    wintypes.ULONG,         # In  Length
    FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS)  # In  FileInformationClass

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# system call to retrieve list of PIDs currently using the file
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
status = ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, ctypes.byref(iosb),
                                      ctypes.byref(info),
                                      ctypes.sizeof(info),
                                      FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation)
pidList = info.ProcessIdList[0:info.NumberOfProcessIdsInList]
print(pidList)
```

Answer (score 3):

There have new PowerToys available from Microsoft.

`File Locksmith` utility for Windows | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/file-locksmith

> After installing PowerToys, right-click on one or more selected files in File Explorer, and then select What's using this file? from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

The above upvoted answers cover situations where a program process is holding the file handle open, which (fortunately) is most of the time - however in some cases (as is occurring on this system at the moment), the system itself holds a file handle open.

You can identify this situation by following the instructions to find the file handle holding process with process explorer above, and noting that the process name is listed as 'system', or by following the the instructions using resource monitor and noting that no image is shown having a filehandle open on your file of interest (Although obviously something does as you can't edit/delete etc the file).

If that happens, your option (so far as I'm aware) is to restart - or forget about doing anything with that file.

Answer (score 1):

I got turned on to the [Free Extended Task Manager](http://www.extensoft.com/?p=free_task_manager) a while ago by Jeremy Zawodny's blog, and it's great for tracking down further info on processes too.  +1 for Process Explorer as above, too, especially for killing processes that the standard Task Manager won't end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool FILEMON and shows open files and handles. Its hard to keep up with its display if you watch it live, it does so quickly. But you can stop it from displaying live and you can watch all file open/write activity. Now owned by Microsoft but originally by Sysinternals

Comment: The updated version of this is process monitor. You can get it here:[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)